# Excel record is insert in Sql DataBase

Tags: sql, excel

My problem is:

Excel file DATA is like this:

```
id     class               unit test 1                      unit test 2
                      eng     math      sci              eng    math   sci
1       v-a           20       15       22               16      18     ab
2       v-b           14       ab       20               19      17     20
```

The table in the database is this:

```
id    class      subject        marks      test_category
1      v-a        eng            20              UT-1
1      v-a        eng            16              UT-2
1      v-a        math           15              UT-1
1      v-a        math           18              UT-2
1      v-a        sci            22              UT-1
1      v-a        sci            null            UT-2
2      v-b        eng            14              UT-1
2      v-b        eng            19              UT-2
2      v-b        math           null            UT-1
2      v-b        math           17              UT-2
2      v-b        sci            20              UT-1
2      v-b        sci            20              UT-2
```

In data base column must be same as shown. But what I need is to insert whole record as shown in excel file. Excel file have ab cell.  Here database insert null value.

In ASP project ON button click event all the record present in excel file should be inserted in database..

I would like to do this in aspx.cs (C# code to achive this).

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the Excel data in another Excel worksheet to the database format by using the following approach:

(Assumptions: data is in Sheet1, columns A to H, with row 1 being ID, class, unit test, row 2 eng, math, ... and row 3+ the data:

In a new sheets, use the following formula (starting in row 2)

- Col A ("Temp col"): `=IF(ISTEXT(A1),1,IF(A1=6,1,A1+1))`
- Col B ("id"): `=IF(ISTEXT(B1),1,IF(A1=1,B1+1,B1))`
- Col C ("class") `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:B$,B2+1)`
- Col D ("subject") `=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$H$2,1,A2)`
- Col F ("marks") `=INDEX(Sheet1!$C:H$,B2+1,A2)`
- Col G ("test category") `=IF(A2<4,"UT-1","UT-2")`

Now you only need to copy the row 2 six times the number of your original data rows. - and then import this table.